# angular reactive forms create checkbox matrix

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-reactive-forms

I stuck on implementing a matrix with checkboxes.

there are 4 static columns and there are dynamic rows with titles.

[image]

how to create a reactive form with this task?

dinamic rows are comming like this.

```
 @Input()
  set dealers(deal: Array<IDealer>) {
    deal.map(el =>
      this.roles.push(
        new FormGroup({
          dealerId: new FormControl(el.dealerId),
          roleIds: new FormArray([])
        })
      )
    );
```

and it works one way. I would need to check the boxes from the controller.(Edit mode)

```
  toggleMe($event) {
    const t = this.userForm.get('roles') as FormArray;

    const roleName = $event.target.id.split('_')[0];
    const dealerId = $event.target.id.split('_')[1];
    const dealerRoleForm = t.value.filter(d => d.dealerId === dealerId)[0];

    if (dealerRoleForm.roleIds.includes(roleName)) {
      dealerRoleForm.roleIds = dealerRoleForm.roleIds.filter(
        v => v !== roleName
      );
    } else {
      dealerRoleForm.roleIds.push(roleName);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you written some code?

Comment: updated. hope it helps to get a better picture